# I am not getting Users on UserScreen in expo-react-native-awsamplify app

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify, mobile-application

Hey I am creating a messanger using react native, expo and aws amplify
this is my a code snipppet from userItem file

```html
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import { DataStore } from '@aws-amplify/datastore';
import { ChatRoom, User, ChatRoomUser } from '../../src/models';

export default function UserItem({ user }) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const onPress = async () => {
    const newChatRoom = await DataStore.save(new ChatRoom({ newMessages: 0 }));

    const authUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
    const dbUser = await DataStore.query(User, authUser.attributes.sub);

      new ChatRoomUser({
        user,
        chatroom: newChatRoom,
      })
    );

    navigation.navigate('ChatRoom', { id: newChatRoom.id });
  };

  return (
    <Pressable onPress={onPress} style={styles.container}>
      <Image source={{ uri: user.imageUri }} style={styles.image} />

      <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.name}>{user.name}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </Pressable>
  );
}
```

and this is my UserScreen code

```html
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { DataStore } from '@aws-amplify/datastore';
import UserItem from '../components/UserItem';
import { User } from '../src/models';

export default function UsersScreen() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    DataStore.query(User).then(setUsers);
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.page}>
      <FlatList
        data={users}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <UserItem user={item} />}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

but I am getting 2 message in console

```html
INFO] 37:36.850 Reachability - subscribing to reachability in React Native
[INFO] 37:37.118 Reachability - Notifying reachability change true
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Object {
  "data": Object {
    "syncUsers": null,
  },
  "errors": Array [
    Object {
      "locations": null,
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable type: 'AWSDateTime' within parent 'User' (/syncUsers/items[0]/createdAt)",
```

I have tried deleting my users from DynamoDb and then added new users in it but the error persists. I think I have to reset my aws-amplify json file but I do not how.